# Autocorrelation of Addition of Two Independent Signals

Tags: autocorrelation, cross-correlation, random-process, stationary

Given a random signal $ Z \left( t \right) $ which is addition of two independent signals $ X \left( t \right) $ and $ Y \left( t \right) $ with constant parameters $ a $ and $ b $:

$$ Z (t) = aX(t) + bY (t) $$

If the [auto correlation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation) of $ R_{XX} \left( \tau \right) $ and $ R_{YY} \left( \tau \right) $ is known (Assume both are [Stationary Signals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process)).
What would be the Auto correlation function of $ Z \left( t \right) $?

Is it given by (I skipped the steps):

$$ {R}_{ZZ} \left( \tau \right) = a^2 R_{XX} \left( \tau \right) + b^2 R_{YY}\left( \tau \right) $$

I neglected the $ {R}_{XY} \left( \tau \right) $ contribution because it is zero as $ X \left( t \right) \perp Y \left( t \right) $ (Independent Random Signals).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct as the Cross Correlation function vanishes.
This has the implicit assumption the process has zero mean (Actually, at least one of them).

Namely, in order to have $ {R}_{XY} \left( \tau \right) = 0 $ having $ X \left( t \right) \perp Y \left( t \right) $ isn't enough. It is required that at least of them has zero mean (Namely, $ \mathbb{E} \left[ X \left( t \right) \right] = 0 $, $ \mathbb{E} \left[ Y \left( t \right) \right] = 0 $ or both).

Pay attention that in practice for a single realization the empirical cross correlation won't vanish.

**Remark**
At the above we use correlation as defined in the context of signal processing.

Comment: just a minor point. If you're going to use $\tau$ to denote Z's correlation lag,  then you should use it for x and y also. otherwise, the assumption is usually that $\tau = 0$ which can possibly confuse readers.

Comment: I disagree, E(x y)=E(x)E(y) when x and y are independent.

Comment: What here not to agree? He states the variables are independent. I implicitly assume each is centered as well.

Comment: @Royi You implicitly assumed that  it was centered.  Assumptions should be explicit. Neither you or the OP state that it is "centered."  If the processes are not "centered," do you contend that your answer is correct of not? So what's not to agree, It's wrong as is.

Comment: @StanleyPawlukiewicz, I updated the question to make the implicit assumption explicit. Yet I'd say that no one would use the Auto Correlation Function for non centered signals (What's the point of using the ACF for analysis of the data in that case?). So think the above is all about the Autocovariance Function.

Comment: Ok, I endorsed your answer and deleted mine so confusion is avoided.

Comment: @Royi: Can you explain the $\tau$ term. In fact, could you explain the equation in words ? Thanks.

Comment: @markleeds, I edited the question to be clearer. Does it make sense to you now?

Comment: @Royi:  It makes a ton more sense.  And thanks for putting the $\tau$ on the RHS also. So, I'm good.  One  thing and I don't want to drag this out ( same terminology issue has occurred before )  but correlation for DSPers, must be  covariance for statisticians because the formula implies that one would could make the z correlation  as large as one wanted by increasing a or b and, in statistics,  correlation can only be between -1 and +1. . Still,  I'm good  as long I think of it as covariance. of z at lag $\tau$.  Of course, I'm not asking anyone else to think of it that way. .Thanks again..

Comment: @Royi: The link you sent explains the difference in definitions between DSP and statistics,  particularly immediately under the signal processing section. Nice find.